# After longpress, UITableViewCell need two clicks to get selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, long-press

I'm implementing long press in `UITableViewCell` using following code. Everything works fine except that when long press is over I have to click two times on a cell to select it.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
longPress.delegate = self;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

Does anybody knows the reason behind this behavior ?
Thanks.

Comment: does your problem occurs only for the cell on which the long press occurred or for any cell in the table view? if only for the cell with the long press, the table view probably considers the cell selected after the long press, so two click to unselect it then select it back. If it is the cas I would advise your to unselect the tableviewcell inside of your handleLongPress: method.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. This occures for all cell in table view, not for selected one only.

Comment: What does your table view delegates look like? Specifically cellForRowAtIndexPath and didSelectRowAtIndexPath.